# Need a KVM setup to support HDMI and DisplayPort input with DVI or HDMI output

Tags: hdmi, kvm-switch, displayport

Here is what I want to connect via KVM to have one monitor and keyboard/mouse:

- 1st Work laptop (HP EliteBook 8560P) with a DisplayPort and VGA video output - I bought a passive DisplayPort to HDMI converter
- 2nd Work laptop (Dell) with an HDMI and VGA video output Personal laptop
- Personal laptop (Sony vpvf2390x) with an HDMI and VGA video output
- Personal desktop (nvidia card) with an HDMI and DVI and VGA video output

I want to connect these to an HP 23" LED monitor (HP2311x) that takes DVI, VGA, and HDMI video input and use my Logitech mouse/keyboard via their unified receiver.

I made an attempt at this using a [SIIG 4x1 USB HDMI KVM Switch CE-KV0111-S1](http://www.siig.com/it-products/kvms/hdmi/4x1-usb-hdmi-kvm-switch.html). This works great for everything except the HP laptop with the DisplayPort. With the DP to HDMI converter I can get the video to work going straight to the external monitor but not when it is routed through the KVM switch.

Are there any products that handle HDMI & DP input with HDMI or DVI output? Do I need a different DP to HDMI converter? Or should I convert everything to DVI for input? Or should I convert the HDMI's to DP and use a DP KVM switch?

Thanks

---

I talked to a tech at KanexPro.com and found out that there isn't such a product on the market. They have something similar [Kanexpro DP KVM](http://www.kanexpro.com/item/?id=DPKVM2P) which would work if I had only DP inputs.

There isn't a way to convert HDMI to DP or DP to HDMI and run through a KVM Switch due to how HDMI works.

The tech's recommendation was to convert both to DVI which **might work** or get a USB switch and use the different inputs on the back of the monitor for my different computers (which would leave me switching the monitor and the USB switch).

Lastly he asked if I had VGA outputs on my computers which led to this idea: use the VGA outputs (left those off the question originally) if they support the native resolution of my monitor (1920x1080) and find a KVM which supports that resolution using VGA input and HDMI/DVI/VGA output.

Hope this helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I usually vote to close shopping recommendations. But I think this falls under *"Does a thing like this exists at all?"* and should remain open.

Comment: This is actually going to get closed! about to edit my question with the reason.